# The change is gone in editing page when remove pictures wuth turbo_frame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

I made some change in edit page and then remove some pictures without refreshing page since turbo_frame, and if I click "update" the page refresh and the change in text are gone, it only actually update if I click for second time. For example, the original edit page looks like this[before click update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UScFC.png). I removeed all pictures and changed description to "456" and clicked "update" the page just refreshed and stay in edit page, however the description stored back to "123" like this [after click update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4N2m.png). The the page actually update if I click "update" again, wondering how to fix this?

Expected result: remove the pictures without refreshing page and update the page with changed description content when click ""update.

I got this in terminal if I click "update" after remove pictures and made change in description

```
15:00:47 web.1  | Started PATCH "/products/11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-21 15:00:47 +0800
15:00:47 web.1  | Processing by ProductsController#update as TURBO_STREAM
15:00:47 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "product"=>{"name"=>"demo", "description"=>"456", "pictures"=>["", "eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBa2dCIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--78e77267b308507009d75e994fa41632650269e1", "eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBa2tCIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--2e611899e93b50023cdcb9d0828ffb2cb429c42e", "eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBa29CIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--32146a6e6e2158b3e9a3e566bb4b1eb2b810b9f6"]}, "commit"=>"Update Product", "id"=>"11"}
15:00:47 web.1  |   Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:65:in `set_product'
15:00:47 web.1  | DEPRECATION WARNING: config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.1. Make sure that your code works well with config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many set to true before upgrading. To append new attachables to the Active Storage association, prefer using `attach`. Using association setter would result in purging the existing attached attachments and replacing them with new ones. (called from block in update at /home/cc/ror/hongda/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41)
15:00:47 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
15:00:47 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" INNER JOIN "active_storage_attachments" ON "active_storage_blobs"."id" = "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ?  [["record_id", 11], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "pictures"]]
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
15:00:47 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 328], ["LIMIT", 1]]
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
15:00:47 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
15:00:47 web.1  | Completed 404 Not Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 4581)
15:00:47 web.1  |
15:00:47 web.1  |
15:00:47 web.1  |
15:00:47 web.1  | ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=328):
15:00:47 web.1  |
15:00:47 web.1  | app/controllers/products_controller.rb:41:in `block in update'
15:00:47 web.1  | app/controllers/products_controller.rb:40:in `update'
15:00:47 web.1  | Started GET "/products/11/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-21 15:00:47 +0800
15:00:47 web.1  | Processing by ProductsController#edit as HTML
15:00:47 web.1  |   Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
15:00:47 web.1  |   Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:65:in `set_product'
15:00:47 web.1  |   Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
15:00:47 web.1  |   Rendering products/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
15:00:47 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 11], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "pictures"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.erb:26
15:00:47 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ?  [["record_id", 11], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "pictures"]]
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/views/products/_form.html.erb:27
15:00:47 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 330], ["LIMIT", 1]]
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/models/product.rb:7:in `picture_as_thumbnail'
15:00:47 web.1  |   ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_variant_records".* FROM "active_storage_variant_records" WHERE "active_storage_variant_records"."blob_id" = ? AND "active_storage_variant_records"."variation_digest" = ? LIMIT ?  [["blob_id", 330], ["variation_digest", "6x8KFtM/8O22vFlQ4EVqBuGjN8Q="], ["LIMIT", 1]]
15:00:47 web.1  |   ↳ app/models/product.rb:8:in `picture_as_thumbnail'
15:00:47 web.1  |   Rendered products/_form.html.erb (Duration: 15.0ms | Allocations: 5039)
15:00:47 web.1  |   Rendered products/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 15.8ms | Allocations: 5186)
15:00:47 web.1  |   Rendered /home/cc/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.1/gems/hotwire-livereload-1.2.3/app/views/hotwire/livereload/_head_action_cable.html.erb (Duration: 2.5ms | Allocations: 738)
15:00:47 web.1  |   Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 8)
15:00:47 web.1  |   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 31.4ms | Allocations: 14486)
15:00:47 web.1  | Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 31.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 15226)
15:00:47 web.1  |
15:00:47 web.1  |
15:00:47 web.1  | Finished "/cable" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-21 15:00:47 +0800
15:00:47 web.1  | Hotwire::Livereload::ReloadChannel stopped streaming from hotwire-reload
15:00:47 web.1  | Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-21 15:00:47 +0800
15:00:47 web.1  | Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-21 15:00:47 +0800
15:00:47 web.1  | Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
15:00:47 web.1  | Hotwire::Livereload::ReloadChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
15:00:47 web.1  | Hotwire::Livereload::ReloadChannel is streaming from hotwire-reload
```

These are the controller, model, routes, and views

controller

```rb
class Products::PicturesController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::RecordIdentifier
  before_action :set_product

  def destroy
    @picture = @product.pictures.find(params[:blob_id])
    @picture.purge_later
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_product_path(@product) }
      format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.remove(dom_id(@picture, :picture))}
    end
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end
end
```

views

```rb
<div>
    <%= form.file_field :pictures, multiple: true %>
    <% if @product.pictures.attached? %>
      <% @product.pictures.each do |picture| %>
        <div id="<%= dom_id(picture, :picture) %>">
          <%= link_to image_tag(product.picture_as_thumbnail(picture)), picture %>
          <%= link_to "remove picture", product_picture_path(@product, blob_id: picture.blob_id), data: { turbo_method: :delete} %>
        </div>
        <%= form.hidden_field :pictures, multiple: true, value: picture.signed_id %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

routes

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'products#home'
  resources :products do 
    resources :pictures, only: [:destroy], module: :products
  end
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
end
```

model

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :pictures

  def picture_as_thumbnail(pic)
    return unless pic.content_type.in?(%W[image/jpeg image/png])
    pic.variant(resize_to_limit: [200, 200]).processed
  end
end
```

Comment: There is no destroy action in your log. It is also unclear what is your question

Comment: The issue is the product originally is 
[name: demo
description: 123
files: picture1, picture2...]
, then if I remove all files and change dextription to "456" then click update => the page just refresh instead of update the post, and restores likes this:
[ name: demo
description: 123
files: nil ]
and I have to click update again to actually update the post.